# Invalid Value Operator '<'(less than)sign when passed as -query_filter in MLCP

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp

I am using MLCP(Marklogic Content Pump) for copying content from one database to another. In this i'm using **-query_filter** option and its value is a cts:query in XML serialized format of a set of cts:element-range-query wrapped in cts:and-query :

```
<cts:and-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
  <cts:element-range-query operator=">">
    <cts:element xmlns:c="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/core">c:released-on</cts:element>
    <cts:value xsi:type="xs:dateTime" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2000-12-21T00:00:00Z</cts:value>
  </cts:element-range-query>
  <cts:element-range-query operator="&lt;">
    <cts:element xmlns:c="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/core">c:released-on</cts:element>
    <cts:value xsi:type="xs:dateTime" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2016-12-21T00:00:00Z</cts:value>
  </cts:element-range-query>
</cts:and-query>
```

Now, the above query returns valid result when executed on ML Qconsole, but when passed in -query_filter option of MLCP, it gives the error saying **'Invalid attribute value character '<'** .

The version of Marklogic and MLCP is 8.0-5.

On further digging into this I observed that the issue is only when the operator value is **less than '<'**

***Note: I have configured a valid range-index on the database for the element "released-on"**.*

Answer (score 1):

**MarkLogic** encourages the use of options files when using a cts query serialized as **XML**, because special characters can be interpreted by the underlying OS on the command line.

My first guess would be to try creating a file, say, `options.txt` with the content:

```
--query_filter
<cts:and-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
  <cts:element-range-query operator=">">
    <cts:element xmlns:c="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/core">c:released-on</cts:element>
    <cts:value xsi:type="xs:dateTime" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2000-12-21T00:00:00Z</cts:value>
  </cts:element-range-query>
  <cts:element-range-query operator="&lt;">
    <cts:element xmlns:c="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/core">c:released-on</cts:element>
    <cts:value xsi:type="xs:dateTime" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2016-12-21T00:00:00Z</cts:value>
  </cts:element-range-query>
</cts:and-query>
```

(You may have to make all the **XML** fit on the same line of that file though)

and then invoke **MLCP** with

> mlcp.sh -options_file options.txt ...

Comment: That's exactly what i'm doing currently. All the concerned options are wrapped in a options.txt file and I'm executing the same command mentioned above.

Comment: I see. It sounds strange indeed, because the XML is well-formed as it is. Something I had in mind in case there's a bug somewhere and "&lt;" gets resolved to "<" too early in the pipeline: have you tried "&amp;lt;" instead "&lt;"?

Comment: I tried using '&amp;lt;' as well but got the same error

Comment: Could the version of the old database be less than 4.0? MarkLogic documents that it used to incorrectly allow for "<" in attributes. Maybe there is somewhere else (query, data) where this character appears.